# Denying access to some databases

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, audit

I need to deny a user access to certain databases in the SQL Server 2019 instance. The user should however be able to migrate all the other databases in the instance to another instance.

- What is the safest server role to give the login?
- Is setting up a database Audit Policy the best way to monitor the user's activities as well as activities on the denied databases?

Thank you

Comment: Are the databases that would need to be migrated routinely backed up?

Comment: How is the user going to be migrating these databases? For example, by doing a backup and restore.

Comment: Thank you so much @J.D. yes, the databases to be migrated are routinely backed up and they are many. The databases the user is to be denied access to are just a handful.

Comment: Thank you so much @ThomA. yes, the migration is to be by backup, copy the backup files over, and restore them in the new instance,  and they are many databases.

Comment: So the person needs permission to `BACKUP` databases, but explicitly not be able to `BACKUP` or access these other databases?

Comment: Thank you again @ThomA. I think I may not have explained the request well, let me try again. Thank you for your patience. So, this user needs to be able to (1) do the backup of several databases in the source SQL instance to a location that will be provided for them (2) should not be able to backup or as much as access, say 10 databases (3) copy the backup files he took from the source location to the target location. (4) restore the databases in the target instance. In the event that those 10 denied databases already exist in the target, the user should be denied access to them. (5)add to AGs

Answer (score 0):

> I need to deny a user access to certain databases in the SQL Server 2019 instance...

> What is the safest server role to give the login?

None. Don't provision any database access to the user on this server, as it's not needed to accomplish what you want.

> The user should however be able to migrate all the other databases in the instance to another instance.

This is more of an infrastructure question then. They don't need any access internally to database instance, as previously mentioned. They just need folder access to where the backup files live. And the databases you don't want them to have access to should be backed up to a different folder (that the user doesn't have access to) than where the databases they should have access to are backed up.

Simple folder structuring and permissions provisioning will accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you again @J.D. I think I may not have explained the request well, let me try again. Thank you for your patience. So, this user needs to be able to (1) do the backup of several databases in the source SQL instance to a location that will be provided for them (2) should not be able to backup or as much as access, say 10 databases (3) copy the backup files he took from the source location to the target location. (4) restore the databases in the target instance. In the event that those 10 denied databases already exist in the target, the user should be denied access to them. (5)add  to AGs

Comment: @PTL_SQL No problem. So to make sure I fully understand, besides the already routine backups that are created, this user needs the ability to create new backups of certain databases?

Comment: Thanks for your help always @JD, very much appreciated. Yes, you are correct. When this exercise is ready to be done, the account will need to (1) take the full database backups at that point in time, but should not be able to backup the denied databases. (2) then copy from source to target location (3) restore the databases to the target instance. (4) the databases are then added to the Availability Group in the target instance.  In the event that the denied databases already exist in target, that account should not be able to access them